# Where can I get list of tokens that allow direct conversion to ether and not just from token to token?

Tags: tokens, exchanges, exchange-api

Most tokens simply utilize the ERC20 functions transferfrom/transferto which just use some balances to add from one user to another - but what are the ones who allow you to:

1. buy token
2. cashout to ether such as: withdraw (msg.sender.transfer (tokensbought);)

Can something like this be done with WETH somehow? (wrapped ether).

I am just looking for a way to get around pricey/scammy exchanges where withdrawal will cost money...not to mention lack of liquidity. Thanx

Comment: OK, looks like this may be something I am looking for? Exchange contract? https://etherscan.io/address/0x2a0c0dbecc7e4d658f48e01e3fa353f44050c208#code

Comment: ^ I mean this above is still exchange but: it's a contract so...no more KYC I hope + no "hidden fees", no lack of liquidity/fake liquidity. Basically if IDEXv have the token I should be able to buy it and then hit 'withdraw'...they have msg.sender.send so...likely this should work.